# python: raw_input function back to top again

Tags: python

I have a raw_function looks like:
    number = raw_input('number (empty to finish): ')

```
if len(number) == 0:
    print
    print
    print 'finished'
    print
    print
    return def()

else:
    pass




while True:
    try:
        column2 = int(raw_input('Enter column: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'You did not supply an integer. Please try again. '
```

When i finish answering my second raw_input, I would like to return to first raw_input.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read _any_ tutorials on Python or are you hoping we'll train you up?

Comment: the `else: pass` doesn't serve any function and could (should) safely be eliminated. There are also a lot of unnecessary blank lines .. take a look at [**PEP 8**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the style Guide for Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
   while True:
     number = raw_input('number (empty to finish): ')
     if not number:
        print "\n\nfinished\n\n\n"
        return def()
     while True:
        try:
            column2 = int(raw_input('Enter column: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print 'You did not supply an integer. Please try again. '
```

Comment: since `number` is a string, it's more pythonic just to check for empty string with `if number`